# how to apply R script on all of my data knowing that i use 2 different extension in my code

Tags: r, dataframe

I have create a R script that analyse and manipulate 2 different data frame extension, for exemple one task is to extract certain values from data and export it as a .txt file, here is the begining of my script and the data files that i use:

```
setwd('C:\\Users\\Zack\\Documents\\RScripts\***')

heat_data="***.heat"
time ="***.timestamp"
ts_heat = read.table(heat_data)
ts_heat = ts_heat[-1,]
rownames(ts_heat) <- NULL
ts_time = read.table(time)
back_heat = subset(ts_heat, V3 == 'H')
back_time = ts_time$V1
library(data.table)
datDT[, newcol := fcoalesce(
nafill(fifelse(track == "H", back_time, NA_real_), type = "locf"),
0)]
last_heat = subset(ts_heat, V3 == 'H')
last_time = last_heat$newcol
x = back_time - last_heat
dataest = data.frame(back_time , x)
write_tsv(dataestimation, file="dataestimation.txt")
```

I than use those 2 files to calculate and extract specific values.
So can anyone plz tell me how can I run this script on each and every .heat and .timestamp files.
My objective is to calculate and extract this values for each file. I note that each file contain
.heat and .timestamp. I note also that I am a windows user.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `list.files`

```r
heat_data <- list.files(pattern = ".*.heat")
time <- list.files(pattern = ".*.timestamp")
```

and then process each file in a loop (or use `lapply`)

```r
for (i in heat_data) {
    h <- read.table(i)
    # other code
}

for (j in time) {
    t <- read.table(j)
    # other code
}
```

you may want to pass the path to `list.files` as well instead of using `setwd`:

```r
heat_data <- list.files("your/path/", pattern = ".*.heat")
```

**After edit question**

Let's say you have 3 `.heat` files and 3 `.timestamp` files in your path named

```
1.heat
2.heat
3.heat
1.timestamp
2.timestamp
3.timestamp
```

so there is a correspondence between `heat` and `timestamp` (given by the file name).

You can read these files with

```r
heat_data <- list.files("your/path/", pattern = ".*.heat")
time <- list.files("your/path/", pattern = ".*.timestamp")
```

At this point, create a function that does exactly what you want. This function takes as input only an index and two paths

```
function (i, heat_data, time) {
   ts_heat <- read.table (heat_data[i])
   ts_time <- read.table (time[i])
   
   #
   # other code
   #
   
   write_tsv(dataestimation, file = paste ("dataestimation", i, ".txt", sep = ""))
}
```

This way you will have files named `dataestimation_1.txt`, `dataestimation_2.txt` and `dataestimation_3.txt`.

Finally use `lapply` to call the function for all files in the folder

```r
lapply (1: 3, heat_data, time)
```

This is just one of the possible ways to proceed.

Comment: actually my code use the 2 files, for example i use those 2 .heat and .timestamp files to do the calculation and to extract a .txt file. In your answer you suggest that i do 2 loop and to put the code that belong to each file in a loop, or did i get you wrong?

Comment: without a minimum reproducible example it is difficult to answer. You asked how to read multiple files with a specific extension and I tried to answer that question. How to process these files is another question and more information is needed to answer! I hope I was helpful. If yes, please upvote my answer and accept it

Comment: I edited my question to give more specification. hope that you can help me to find a way to process/apply my script to all the .heat and .timestamp files. (unfortunately I am not yet allowed to upvote your answer because that i don't have 15 reputations)